# Error: Table users for model User was not found in datasource default in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, fetch, record

I am facing a problem when I fetch record from database in cakephp. Always an error is showing.Error: Table users for model User was not found in datasource default.

Comment: pls. help. I can't get the record from DB anyway in cakephp.

Comment: put you code here to help you on this ...

Comment: check the db u are using for table 'users'.

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp has strict naming conventions.
Try to manually adjust the database table in your model

> public $useTable = 'user'; // or whatever your database table is called like